# Crawling a site with iframe

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl data from [this](https://www.epc.shell.com/) site. It uses multiple `iframes` for different components.

When I try to open one of the [iframe url](https://www.epc.shell.com/welcome.asp) in browser, it opens in that particular session but in another icognito/private session it doesn't. Same happens when I try to do this via `requests` or `wget`.

I have tried using requests along with session, then also it doesn't work. Here is my code snippet

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.epc.shell.com/')
r = s.get('https://www.epc.shell.com/welcome.asp')
r.text
```

The last line only returns the javascript text with error that URL is invalid.

I know Selenium can solve this problem but I am considering it as last option.

Is it possible to crawl this URL with `requests` (*or without using Javascript*)? If yes, any help would be appreciated. If no, is there any alternative lightweight Javascript library in Python that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue can be easily solved by adding [custom headers](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) to your requests, all in all, your code should look like this:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
s.get('https://www.epc.shell.com/', headers = headers)
r = s.get('https://www.epc.shell.com/welcome.asp', headers = headers)

print(r.text)
```

*(Do note that it is almost always recommended to use headers when sending requests)*.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You are right. I used headers but not during creating session.. thanks..